# Why inline CSS is not working on component in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm using a component in react.

```
import style from "../../Style/Styles.module.scss";


const Anchor = (props) => {
  return <a className={style["anchorTags"]} href={props.href}>{props.title}</a>;
};

export default Anchor;
```

where I have already written CSS for this component in my SCSS file.

```
.anchorTags {
    border: 2px solid $Very-Light-Gray;
    color: $Very-Light-Gray;
}
```

but when I'm writing inline css in a component when using this on another component it is not working.

```
import style from "../../Style/Styles.module.scss";
import Anchor from "./achortag";

<Anchor
          style={{ paddingBlock: "0.7em", paddingInline: "2em" }}
          href="/viewPlan"
          title="VIEW PLANS"
        />
```

Please share your suggestion on how this will work?

Comment: Have you checked if the styles appear in dev tools?

Comment: please output what the html looks like in the dev tools

Comment: in React Developer Tools where we can see the DOM tree of components? @Konrad

Answer (score 4):

In Anchor component:

```js
const Anchor = (props) => {
  return (
    <a className={style.anchorTags} href="#" style={props.style}>
      {props.title}
    </a>
  );
};

export default Anchor;
```

or use the spread operator, this will add any additional attributes:

```js
const Anchor = (props) => {
  return (
    <a className={style.anchorTags} href="#" {...props}>
      {props.title}
    </a>
  );
};

export default Anchor;
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the desired style, you must use this syntax:

```
import style from "../../Style/Styles.module.scss";

const Anchor = (props) => (
  <a className={style.anchorTags} href={props.href} {...props}>{props.title}</a>;
);

export default Anchor;
```

For more information, you can read this ([Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)).