# React component class styles not getting applied

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple lightbox component that uses a material-ui modal and has a style sheet. The component and the css look like this.

**Lightbox.tsx**

```
import { Modal } from '@material-ui/core';
import { CloseOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
import styles from './Lightbox.module.css';

export default function Lightbox(props: any) {
  return (
    <Modal
      className={styles.modal}
      open={props.open}
      onClose={props.handleClose}
    >
      <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
        <div className={styles.imageToolbar}>
          <CloseOutlined
            aria-aria-label={props.closeButtonMessage}
            className={styles.toolbarButton}
            data-cy="lightbox-close"
            fontSize="inherit"
            onClick={props.handleClose}
            role="button"
          />
        </div>
        <img src={props.url} className={styles.image} title={props.name} />
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

**Lightbox.module.css**

```
.modal {
  z-index: 2147483640 !important;
}

.imageContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

.imageToolbar {
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.toolbarButton {
  color: #cccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.toolbarButton:hover {
  color: #ffff;
}
```

The component is rendered inside another component like so:

```
<Lightbox
   closeButtonMessage={formatMessage(closeMessageDescriptor)}
   url={url}
   name={name}
   handleOpen={handleOpen}
   handleClose={handleClose}
   open={open}
/>
```

When the application is run, the class names are present on the elements however, the styles are missing.

Elements in debugger console: [Rendered elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOQX1.png)

Rendered CSS for the elements: [Style not rendering for the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzCY5.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I need to use CSS style sheet as mentioned in my example and not inline CSS styles.

Since I am new to react, I have tried looking at other components in the project I am currently working on. This method of using CSS style works for other components. Since I am new to React, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why inline CSS is not working on component in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360709/why-inline-css-is-not-working-on-component-in-react)

Comment: @MahdiSamavi I am not trying to apply styles inline. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @MahdiSamavi It's only one component. Lightbox.tsx is the component and Lightbox.module.css is the corresponding CSS file.

Comment: Do you see an error in the console section?

Comment: Probably could not import the style file.

Comment: @MahdiSamavi There is no error in the debugger console. I can see the styles being loaded in the bundled CSS as well.